# Check if a device is iOS inside an HTML email

Tags: ios, html, ios6, html-email

Is it possible to check if a device is iOS inside an HTML email?

I want to display Apple and Google maps schema links to the native apps, but only if the device supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a look online and couldn't even find a hack in CSS. Shame there is no equivalent to the `<!--[if gte mso 9]>` tags. It looks like the answer is technically no...

Good thing in this case is that Mac has different CSS support to other clients, so you can leverage that as a work around in email.

Try using one of the CSS selectors (Nth child for example). These are [CSS attributes that only mac recognizes](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Theoretically you could hide something by default and set the Nth child selector to show the Mac only content.

If you were really despirate, you could also display some 'mac only' text using RGBA or HSLA colors on the same color background (making it invisible).

Comment: looks like nth child is the best option for this one, perhaps combined with a media query to prevent it from loading in apple mail. Though this is far from ideal as other clients may support nth child at any time. I don't see too much harm in putting the links there with a disclaimer that they are only for iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the same link in the email, like `example.com/emailLink`, where that endpoint on your server is server-side code (like PHP) detecting the browser and then delivering the link you'd like.

http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/