# detecting the viewer's operating system in an HTML email; serving a banner

Tags: html-email

My client wants me to build a responsive email template with a dynamic area that will serve a different banner depending on which operating system is being used to view the email (targeting iOS, Android and desktops).

I know that if I use some JavaScript in my emailer I risk the email app counting the email as junk. This is not an option if the risk is too high.

Can anyone give me a clear insight or links that would help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to check for all OS's in email as it would involve more than just HTML/CSS. You can however use the limitations of CSS per client and media queries to show or hide different pieces of content however.

In addition to hmhcreative's example which hides/shows mobile vs desktop, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799625/check-if-a-device-is-ios-inside-an-html-email) thread may be useful regarding showing content to only mac clients.

With some clever media queries you can show one ad for desktop, another for mac-only portable devices and a default for everything else. Not a complete solution, but it is close.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one can help. Basically it uses media query to hide the desktop-version banner and show the mobile-version banner.

HTML:

```
<!--FOR DESKTOP-->
<table class="notmobile" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><img style="display:block;" src="[path]/image-desktop.jpg" alt="BANNER" border="0" height="150" width="600" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--//FOR DESKTOP-->

<!--FOR MOBILE-->
<div class="div_for_mobile" style="display: none; width: 0px; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <table class="table_for_mobile" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center" style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#"><img style="display:block;" src="[path]/image-mobile.jpg" alt="BANNER" border="0" height="75" width="320" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--//FOR MOBILE-->
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
div[class=div_for_mobile] {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-height: inherit !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}

table[class=notmobile] {
    display: none !important;
}

table[class=table_for_mobile] {
    display: block !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Thats great for mobile vs desktop but I really wanted to target Mobile OS. So lets say IOS, Android and other. Any Idas on this?

Comment: I would try what John suggested. You may duplicate the HTML markup for mobile version, using separate class name for each of them. Then in your CSS, show the banner for Android first, followed by using :nth-child(n) selector (which only works for iOS devices mail app.) to hide it and show the banner for iOS. Just the idea, I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
div[class=div_for_mobile] {
display: block !important;
width: 100% !important;
max-height: inherit !important;
overflow: visible !important;
}

table[class=notmobile] {
display: none !important;
}

table[class=table_for_mobile] {
display: block !important;
}
.div_for_mobile .table_for_mobile tr :nth-child(2n){ display:none}
.div_for_mobile .table_for_mobile tr :nth-child(3n){ display:block!important;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

For desktop,

```
<table class="notmobile" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
    <td><a href="#"><img style="display:block;" src="img/desktop.jpg" alt="BANNER" border="0" height="150" width="600" /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

For mobile, use this:

```
<div class="div_for_mobile" style="display: none; width: 0px; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
 <table class="table_for_mobile" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="#"><img style="display:block;" src="img/android-test.jpg" alt="BANNER" border="0" height="75" width="320" /></td>
        <td style="display:none"><a href="#"><img style="display:block;" src="img/ios-test.jpg" alt="BANNER" border="0" height="75" width="320" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: But how does this checks the OS version?